What is the purpose of "Return" in Python when i could just use a print in a function?
I am learning about Python and trying to get my head around why i should use the return statement instead of just printing the result.
My course covers the syntax but does not elaborate on WHY you should use return.
For example:
Function with a Print statement
def greet(name):
    print(f"Hello, {name}!")

Functional with a "Return"
def add_numbers(a, b):
    result = a + b
    return result

In both cases above, you can get the output by using the print function.
What is the benefit of using a return?

If you want to do anything other than printing the result, then return is what you want. For example if you wanted to continue doing calculation with the result of add_numbers, then a print would not be very useful.
